# Git - activate hook remotely?

Tags: git, hook, assembla

is there a way to activate a git hook remotely?
I am using some repos at www.assembla.com and I'd like to use them over http. 
But cloning fails since I should run server-update-info on the remote repo. Is there a way to activate the post-update hook remotely via a git command and using the credentials I have for the repo?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to activate hooks remotely ( using the access you have for the repo) since that would be a serious security concern ( unless you have access to the server, of course, which you will not, in this case)

With that said, the error you are seeing means you are doing something wrong and you don't have to have the post-update hook for this to work ( since Assembla are using Smart HTTP anyway) -

1) Make sure you have a recent version of Git ( atleast 1.7)

2) Make sure you have cloned it the right way:

```
git clone https://<username>@git.assembla.com/<spacename>.git
```

http://blog.assembla.com/assemblablog/tabid/12618/bid/70667/Git-over-HTTP.aspx

Comment: Thanks manojlds. Ok git version is good. I'm a bit confused about the url you mentioned. Shall I assume that <username> is actually username:password ? Because this is run automatically and having only username keeps the program waiting for the password. This the last one I just sent https://myusername@git.assembla.com/my_space_name.2.git but that keeps waiting for the password. And with the password I get the did you run git update-server-info on the server question. The funny thing is that sometimes, very few times is goes through, but I can't find the pattern.

Comment: To add more details to this. What I do is actually create the repo with Assembla API, then clone it into my tmp folder, add some files and push it back. But well the clone keeps failing with the have you run update-server-info...So the first clone if an empty repository which causes a warning but that should be ok.

Comment: Apparently yeah I was doing something wrong. Cloning goes ok now. Thanks for the hints. Just to avoid confusion others please note that <username> can be username:password to avoid password question if you are using a script.

Comment: Last update. My problem was a timing issue. I added a sleep between creating a repo and cloning it and the problem is gone.